# org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Users is not mapped [from Users users]

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Can anybody help me out of this situation?

Users.java

```
@Entity  
@Table(name="users")  
public class Users {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id") 
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name="salary")
    private Long salary;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

        //getters and setters    
}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
 <bean id="sessionFactory"   
 class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">

 <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/> 

// Dont Understand whether internaly its reading the class or not!

 <property  name="packagesToScan" value="com.project.entities"/> 

 <property  name="hibernateProperties"> 
 <props>  
 <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>   
 <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> </props>
 </property> 

 </bean>
```

Method from persistence Layer

```
public List<Users> getAllUsers(){

    String queryString = "from Users users";
    List<Users> list =  htemp.find(queryString);
    return list;
}
```

Comment: What problem do you have ?

Comment: Is your entity Users is under the package com.project.entities ?

Comment: Yes it is......its giving error Users not mapped............